# Probability of finding a book in the nth bookshelf?

Tags: probability, statistics

A book has a certain probability p ∈ [0, 1] of being in one of the shelves of a library, n ≥ 2, the probability the book is checked out is 1-p. In this example, what is the probability of finding the book in the n-th bookshelf after unsuccessfully searching the other shelves?

Comment: Can we assume that the book is uniformly placed in any shelf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example of Baye's theorem.

Let $A$ be the event that the book is in the $n$'th shell and let $B$ be the probability the book is not in the first $n-1$ shelves.

You want $P(A|B)$.

By Baye's theorem this is equal to:

$$\frac{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{1\cdot p/n}{1-p + p/n}=\frac{p}{n-pn+p}$$